# How to prove connecting 3 dots to three squares without overlap is impossible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was given this problem to solve by a professor who promised an A if anyone could solve it. I'm nearly certain it is impossible, because at some point you have too many vertices and inevitably box yourself in, but I would like to know how to prove it.

How can you prove that it is impossible to connect every `*` with every `0` without overlapping lines?

```
*    *    *   

0    0    0
```

EDIT: Professor said you get an A if you **solve it**, not prove it's impossible. I'm not even in the class, it was my friend's question, I am just curious.

Comment: Well, it looks like you will be getting a B then :)

Comment: So, if I tell you the answer, then do *I* get the A?

Comment: Your profs is too old school that he/she doesn't even know there 's something called math stackexchage? Half of the class will get A then.

Comment: The prof only offered an A for a solution, not necessarily for a proof that it's imposible!

Comment: There are two proof of this in Chapter 5 of Robin. J. Wilson's book "Introduction to graph theory". One is constructive, the other one uses Euler's formula. If you still are not satisfied, you can look at Chapter 4 of Richard Diestel's book "Graph Theory" (GTM 173) which uses topology to prove the same statement rigorously.

Comment: The drawing requested is a well-known $K_\{3,3\}$ 'utility graph' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water,_gas,_and_electricity which is known to be not planar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph – so the task is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

The problem of connecting these points using edges is a Graph-Theoretic Problem. If you are unfamiliar with graph theory, I suggest readng up on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).

Specifically, we say that a graph is **[planar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)** if it can be drawn such that no edges overlap, as you are trying to do. [Wagner's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Kuratowski.27s_and_Wagner.27s_theorems) states that a graph is planar only if it does not contain $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor.

But the graph you're trying to achieve -- connecting every `*` with every `0` -- is  $K_{3,3}$. And every graph is a minor of itself, so the graph you're trying to achieve contains $K_{3,3}$ as a minor, so it is not planar.

You'll probably want to read up on **complete graphs** to understand this answer. $K_{3,3}$ is the complete bipartite graph on two sets of three vertices.